# line break does not work with swift and outlook 365

Tags: swift, email, outlook

in my app I generate an email and send it via Outlook 365.
In the Emailbody I normally use \n for a new line.
Example
mailStrg = "Hallo zusammen,\n ich hoffe ihr seid alle gesund!\nViele Grüße"

I open with ThirdPartyMailer the Outlook App and pass the mailStrg.
Normally the text in the Mail was like

```
Hallo zusammen,
ich hoffe ihr seid alle gesund!
Viele Grüße
```

But now, I think with Outlook 365 I see this text

```
Hallo zusammen, ich hoffe ihr seid alle gesund!Viele Grüße
```

How do I make outlook do a line break?